# Pentaho pop-up alerting me about connecting to Hadoop repeatedly

Tags: user-interface, popup, pentaho

Working in Pentaho for the first time, on a existing project.
When I launch anything, I get that annoying pop-up that appears each time Pentaho run a block.

The pop up appears again, despite me clicking "OK" or "Cancel":
[image]

My boss told me he had the same problem before and said that he fixed it in some settings in the software but sadly he don't remember where and my queries on Google nor stack overflow failed.

Anyone knows how to turn off these pop-ups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the right distribution in *Tools* > *Hadoop distribution*. 
The alert will no longer occur.

Reference: *"Connect to a Hadoop Cluster in Spoon"* in Hadoop documentation